# Rects Don't Collide with Eachother Even with Colliderect

Tags: python, pygame

```
#Main problem should be around this function
def pick_ups(health_regenerate,damage_buff,speed_increase):
    print("pickups")
    #Checks if player collides with health_regenerate, then makes health = 
    100
    if player.colliderect(health_regenerate):
        print('collidehealth')
        player_health = 100
    if player_2.colliderect(health_regenerate):
        print('collidehealth2')
        player_2_health = 100



    print(damage_buff)
    print(player)
    #if player collides with the damage pickup, bullets should domoredamage
    if player.colliderect(damage_buff):
        print('collide1')  
        for i in range(len(bullets_2)-1,-1,-1):
        if bullets[i].colliderect(player_2):
            damage = 50
            player_2_health -= damage    

    if player_2.colliderect(damage_buff):
       print('collide2')
       for i in range(len(bullets_2)-1,-1,-1):
           if bullets_2[i].colliderect(player):
                damage = 50
                player_health -= damage
    #If player collides with speed_increase pickup, player speed increases
    if player.colliderect(speed_increase):
        print("speed")
        player_speed += 5
    if player_2.colliderect(speed_increase):
        print("speed")
        player_speed += 5


firing = False
firing_2 = False
while True:
    screen.fill(background)
    health_bars(player_health,player_2_health)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,player_colour,player)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,player_2_colour,player_2)
    pick_ups(health_regenerate,damage_buff,speed_increase)
    pygame.time.delay(40)
    events = pygame.event.get()





for event in events:
    player_direction = [0,0]
    player_direction_2 = [0,0]
    player_speed = 2
    player_speed_2 = 2
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        exit()


for obstacle in obstacles:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), obstacle)

for wall in walls:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall, 1)

#PLAYER ONE:
#Movement of player 1 
keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
#Upward
if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] == 1:
    player_direction[1] = -player_speed
    last_direction_y = -1

#Downward
if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] == 1:
    player_direction[1] = player_speed
    last_direction_y = 1
#Left
if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] == 1:
    player_direction[0] = -player_speed
    last_direction_x = -1
#Right
if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] == 1:
    player_direction[0] = player_speed
    last_direction_x = 1
#shoot player 1
if keys_pressed[pygame.K_PERIOD]:
    if not firing:
        shoot_timer = shoot_timer_max
        firing = True
        bullet_direction_x += [last_direction_x]
        bullet_direction_y += [last_direction_y] 
        bullets += [pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, 3, 5)]

if shoot_timer > 0:
    shoot_timer -= 1

    if shoot_timer == 0:
        firing = False

#Shooting while not moving player 1
if player_direction[0] != 0:
    last_direction_x = player_direction[0]

else:
    if last_direction_y != 0:
        last_direction_x = 0
if player_direction[1] != 0:
    last_direction_y = player_direction[1] 
else:
    if last_direction_x != 0:
        last_direction_y = 0
for i in range(len(bullets)):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 222), bullets[i])
    bullets[i] = bullets[i].move(bullet_direction_x[i]*bullet_speed, 
    bullet_direction_y[i]*bullet_speed)

#Bullet Collision 1
for bullet_hit in map_walls:
    for i in range(len(bullets)):
        if bullets[i].collidelist(bullet_hit) >= 0:
            bullets.pop(i)
            bullet_direction_x.pop(i)
            bullet_direction_y.pop(i)
            break
#collision player 1
player = player.move(player_direction[0], 0)
for wall_list in map_walls:
    if player.collidelist(wall_list) >= 0:
            player = player.move(-player_direction[0], 0)
            break
player = player.move(0, player_direction[1])
for wall_list in map_walls:
    if player.collidelist(wall_list) >= 0:
            player = player.move(0, -player_direction[1])
            break

pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(640,360,10,10))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(600,300,10,10))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, yellow,(600,250,10,10))
pygame.display.update()
```

## Problem

I can't seem to get the game to detect that the players collide with the rect objects of health_regenerate, speed increase. And for damage_buff, both players collide with it but it doesn't seem to change the damage output at all.

I spent hours trying to figure out the issue. The pickups draw but won't collide.

Please help, my computer science teacher tried to help me but told me that he didn't know and told me to figure it out myself. I don't know how to use classes or sprites yet because I have no time to learn with this project due really soon.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we can't see where the error originates from.

Comment: I stated at the top of the question in a comment that the function called pick_ups was probably the most likely offender. And this was the most minimal I could do. My full code has about 400 lines.

Comment: Okay, you really can't await help if you post such an incomplete code example. Debugging such code fragments can be very difficult or even impossible if important information is missing. If you're not able to provide a minimal and complete example, you can try to post the complete program, but it's unlikely that the people here will help you if they have to read and analyze so much code and you can expect to be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

thats a lot of code... im not sure what your problem is ... but here is an example

```
import pygame


player = pygame.Rect(10,20,50,50)
pickup = pygame.Rect(100,20,50,50) # not colliding
print player.colliderect(pickup) # 0

#move player
player.left = 85
player.top = 15
# now playwe collides
print player.colliderect(pickup) # 1
```

here is an even more complete example

```
import random

import pygame
import sys


player = pygame.Rect(10,20,50,50)
pickup = pygame.Rect(100,20,50,50) # not colliding
print player.colliderect(pickup) # 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((424, 320))

collide = False
direction=1
while 1:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    player.left += 1*direction
    player.top = random.randint(10,30)
    collide = player.colliderect(pickup)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0) if not collide else (0, 0, 255), player)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 250, 0) if not collide else (200, 200, 255), pickup)
    if player.left > 300 and direction > 0:
        direction = -1
        player.left = 299
    elif player.left < 1 and direction < 0:
        direction = 2
        player.left = 1

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: The thing is, from what I can tell, my collide code is exactly like what was listed above. So maybe it's not a problem in the function.